# mutableArrayValueForKey NSMutableArray crash when removing objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, kvc

I'm running into a crash with the following code. `self.items` is an `NSArray` of `NSManagedObjects` with an `"id"` attribute of type String:

```
NSMutableArray *allIDs = [self.items mutableArrayValueForKey:@"id"];
NSArray *presentIDs = // a subset of allIDs
[allIDs removeObjectsInArray:presentIDs];
```

Here is the crash message:

```
'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "id"; desired type = NSString; given type = __NSArrayM; value = ....
```

Printing it out in debugger reveals that `allID` is a `NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray` instead of `__NSArrayM` for a regular `NSMutableArray`.

So I changed it to this and it works:

`NSMutableArray *allIDs = [[self.items valueForKey:@"id"] mutableCopy];`

What is the difference between these two calls that would make the former crash but the latter work? I suspect it's something to do with KVO and proxy collections but don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect it's something to do with KVO and proxy collections but
>   don't quite understand it.

Right, though not KVO, KVC (Key-Value Coding).

From the *NSKeyValueCoding Protocol Reference*

> **`mutableArrayValueForKey:`**
>
> Returns a mutable array proxy that provides read-write access to an
>   ordered to-many relationship specified by a given key.

In other words, the purpose of `mutableArrayValueForKey:` is to provide mutable access to an immutable array stored in a property of the receiver.

On the other hand, KVC provides a special implementation of `valueForKey:` for properties of type `NSArray` that causes the target array to propagate the `valueForKey:` message to each of its elements, and return an array of all the resulting values.

So in your second example, sending `valueForKey:` to the items array resulted in an array of values obtained by sending `valueForKey:@"id"` to each item in the array. The first example would only work if the items array *itself* had a property named **id** of type `NSArray *`.

Comment: That clears it up. My confusion was thinking `mutableArrayValueForKey:` was the same as a mutable version of `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Yep, I think it's inherently confusing the first time around.